# How I can know if something is initialised in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have some pseudocode that checks if a variable is `null`:

```
Test test;

if (test == null) {
    test = new Test();
}

return test;
```

How would I do something like this in Rust? This is my attempt so far:

```
struct Test {
    time: f64,
    test: Test,
}

impl Test {
    fn get(&self) -> Test {

        if self.test == null {
            // <--

            self.test = Test { time: 1f64 };
        } else {
            self.test
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try creating and using an uninitialized value :)

Comment: @A.B. You're right, I think rephrase the question with what I get, I now feel more stupid my intention is created a singleton

Comment: Your `Test` struct has a field `test` that is the same type as the struct. Did you mean for this to be the case?

Comment: @quornian My intention was to create a singleton, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364415/how-i-can-create-a-simple-basic-singleton

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Uninitialized variables cannot be detected at runtime since the compiler won't let you get that far.

If you wish to store an optional value, however, the [`Option<...>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/) type is handy for that. You can then use `match` or `if let` statements to check:

```
let mut x: Option<f32> = None;
// ...

x = Some(3.5);
// ...

if let Some(value) = x {
    println!("x has value: {}", value);
}
else {
    println!("x is not set");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer to my original question a bit strange, I just did an update, perhaps, you can orient me?