# How I can create a simple basic singleton?

Tags: rust

My intention was to create a singleton, but do not know how to handle this in Rust, I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791532/how-do-i-create-a-global-mutable-singleton) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221504/how-can-you-make-a-safe-static-singleton-in-rust), but not sure if that's the way to create a simple singleton because one speaks of a "mutable singleton" and the other of a "safe-static-singleton".

Comment: I ask this question because in the previous did not explain well, and already has an answer, so I do this and delete the update of the other, to accept the answer without update

Comment: Simple answer would be: you don't. It is almost never good idea to use singletons.

Comment: Please describe *what you want to do* with the singleton. If you aren't mutating something, then there are other options.

Comment: @Shepmaster is not anything in particular, I'm creating things I use in other language, to learn something of Rust. Not mutate, just that it always returns the same instance of the object

Comment: I'd warn against blindly copying concepts from other languages as you are less likely to discover the things that make a language unique and useful. Anyway, it sounds like you want a [constant of some kind](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/const-and-static.html). Follow the instructions to use lazy-static in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27826181/155423) and just skip the wrapping `Mutex`.

Comment: Meta commentary should normally be left in the comments, not the question, and you shouldn't delete your question if it's a duplicate anyway - Stack Overflow uses duplicates to help Googlers find information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A singleton is just a lazily initialized piece of static data. That means you really do want [`lazy-static`](https://github.com/Kimundi/lazy-static.rs).

Note that

> For a given `static ref NAME: TYPE = EXPR;`, the macro generates a unique type that implements `Deref<TYPE>` and stores it in a static with name `NAME`.

which means `NAME` is actually akin to the *constructor* of the "singleton", and `&*NAME` is the "singleton" itself.